# Require factory method when called by controller

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I'm using an angularJS and requireJS seed which you can download here: [LINK](https://github.com/tnajdek/angular-requirejs-seed)

In that seed only the controllers that are called download the relevant controller which is then triggered. I've been trying to call a factory from my controller (with no luck) plus I would like the services/factories only to download the relevant factory if it has been called.

I've attempted to require a function within the factory method (much like the controller) but it is not working.

This is where I left off: [Plunkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/65C3nInQbHlSKjqVg2Hn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user971824.

I've put together something I call couchPotato that lazy-registers just about anything in angular using requirejs and the resolution features of $routeProvider (or any other router that does lazy promise-based resolution.

I've created a plunker based on yours demonstrating how you could do it with couchPotato.  If you take a look at it, I think you'll see that it's a bit simpler because you don't actually create modules for all of the things you register lazily.

couchPotato grew out of some other example apps I found on the web.  What I wanted was a tight way to do the lazy registration and a provider/service combo seemed ideal.  I also wanted to maintain the ability for one component to depend on another, like in your example, you want the controller to depend on the factory... couchPotato lets you specify those dependencies in requirejs syntax.

So your controller, in my rendition, looks like this:

```
define(['app', 'myFactory'], function(app) {
  app.couchPotato.registerController([
    'mycontroller',
    [
      'myFactory',
      function(myFactory) {
        var message = myFactory.getCustomers();
        alert(message);
      }
    ]
  ]);
});
```

In this example, I made the controller, the factory and the value all lazy, but you could pick and choose and have some registered the "old fashioned way" at configuration time and others registered with couchPotato when they're needed for a given route.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Z3v1mszQiiq024po8Ocp?p=preview

A couple of things to note:
1) I put in a default route in order to trigger the lazy loading of your controller, your service (factory) and the version value.
2) I modified your service to append the version just to show how one component can depend on another (the service depends on the version value, the controller depends on the service).

So, within the require configuration, you don't actually specify any of this... it's all done lazily within your route.

```
$routeProvider.when('/',
 $couchPotatoProvider.resolveDependenciesProperty({
  templateUrl:'home.html',
  controller: 'mycontroller',
  dependencies: [
   'mycontroller'
  ]
 })
);
```

Since mycontroller depends on myFactory and myFactory depends on version, by the time your route is displayed they are all available and hooked up.  I put some dummy text in the home.html partial just for kicks, but the controller is assigned by the $routeProvider so you don't actually need to specify it in the template.

couchPotato lives at https://github.com/afterglowtech/angular-couchPotato if you'd like to see a couple of other samples.  I shim'ed it in dependent on angular because I designed it to be usable in cases where an entire application doesn't necessarily use requirejs... thus if you *are* loading angular with requirejs, you need to make couchPotato dependent on angular using the shim/deps technique.

LMK if you have any questions/comments... hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. My main concern here is that my application is not an SPA which is part of the reason why I want to require services only when needed on certain pages. My question to you  is using routes and ng-views a necessity for this to work? There are parts of my application that doesn't need to concern SEO however pages especially the home page need to be crawlable and so I cannot use routes. I do realise that my use case is rather odd but I'm using angularJS for its many benefits that are not just a benefit to SPA's.

Comment: Actually, I made couchPotato specifically with the use case of a CMS in mind -- i.e. a big site that can't afford to load everything all at once.  SEO is a challenge for any app that populates its content with javascript but there are tools/techniques... how does SPA relate to the use of routes? Are you saying you want to have your content in lots of different pages?  Wouldn't you end up re-loading your code all the time?

Comment: Here's one way I know of to tackle SEO with angular: https://github.com/steeve/angular-seo .  I'll see about putting together a plunk that lets you keep the components separate while not requiring $routeProvider... I haven't done any such sample but it should be doable.

Comment: I really appreciate you going out of your way to help. I wanted to avoid the use of routes and ng views because I know robots cannot crawl content injected using javascript. Of course the dynamic content I currently have wont be crawlable but I still had static content and primary navigation that is important for robots. I am intended to have separate pages yes however if there is a proven solution that makes SPA content crawlable then I would like to hear about it too. Requirejs seems to be super cache happy however I dont know whether if its can cache across multiple pages (probably not).

Comment: Another reason why I havent gone completely SPA is because I find directives way too complicated. Creating your own directive to do something seems straight forward enough however creating a directive to get a jquery plugin to work seems to be way too complicated, frustrating and a bit of time waste.

Comment: Yes, requirejs-fetched script will cache across multiple pages if they aren't expired (but the script will be rerun).  I think you're in for a world of hurt if you try to use angular and go from page to page as if you're not using a single app.  You're going to bootstrap your app each time, you're going to rerun all of the module definitions, etc... you don't need to write a single directive to use angular -- remember templates. Based on your concerns, question whether you mean to use angular at all.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/fv3zKBZu8FyQ0q5IrOXs shoehorns in the download and registration of myFactory when the controller is instantiated.  It's not pretty -- in fact it hurt to write it and it hurts to look at it.  There are some things couchPotato could do to make it easier... but seriously, you'll probably have an easier time setting up something that works with SEO within angular's way of doing things, than you will trying to use angular in the way you are... just think of all those CPU cycles... and you won't be able to share any contextual information when you go from page to page...

Comment: Thanks for your help. The missing link for me is knowing how to get jquery plugins to work with angular by creating directives. I think if I cracked that then I would be much more confident moving to SPA's.

Comment: Maybe start with [this approach](http://amitgharat.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/an-approach-to-use-jquery-plugins-with-angularjs/) and then ask on SO if you can't get cranking.

Comment: Is there a way to parse in $http, $scope and $rootScope into a factory from your last example?

Comment: I'm not real clear on what you mean... perhaps it's time for a new SO question?  I don't want to abuse the comments feature too much but I'd be happy to try to help.  Feel free to link to the plunker in your question and please do post a link to it here so I can follow you there!

Comment: Hi, I posted a new question which you can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354093/using-angularjs-service-cookies-in-factory-registered-using-couchpotato