# Using angularjs service ($cookies) in factory registered using couchpotato

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, angularjs-service

I'm using angularjs with couchpotato for help with lazy loading. My question is how do I reference angularjs services like $http, $cookies in my service registered using couchpotato?

The normal angularjs way:

```
factory('MyService', function($cookies) {
  $cookies.message = "hello";
});
```

How do I do the above using angularjs with couchpotato.js?
Below is my service with couchpotato:

```
define(['app'], function(app) {
  app.couchPotato.registerFactory(['myFactory',
    [
      function() {
        var factory = {};

        factory.registerCookie = function(){
          $cookies.message = 'hello';
        };

        return factory;
      }
    ]
  ]);
});
```

Of course the above wont work because I have no reference to $cookies in the factory.

Although the above example is specific to $cookies it is relevant to all angular services like $http, $rootScope etc.

Link to couchpotato.js: [LINK](https://github.com/afterglowtech/angular-couchPotato)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is off the top of my head, but something like this

```
define(['app'], function(app) {
  app.couchPotato.registerFactory(['myFactory',
    [ '$http', '$cookies',
      function($http, $cookies) {
        var factory = {};

        factory.registerCookie = function(){
          $cookies.message = 'hello';
        };

        return factory;
      }
    ]
  ]);
});
```

You could also look at this sample https://github.com/afterglowtech/angular-couchPotato/blob/master/samples/components-demo/js/lazy/controllers/myCtrl1.js which injects $scope

Comment: Thank you this is all I needed to know. I browsed that sample app before, I dont know how that passed me. Thanks again.

Comment: I have a question with regards to using directives with couchpotato. I would be grateful if you could take a look at what I'm doing wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17514812/require-angularjs-directive-using-couchpotato